# Creating Help Documentation for Multiple Excel UDFs

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm collecting a few dozen User Defined Functions and arranging them into a handful of add-ins, organized by topic. Many of my users won't be savvy enough to dig into the VBA, or even know to `Ctrl+A` or `Ctrl+Shift+A` to reveal the parameters. Regardless, knowing the names of the parameters only offers so much help. So I'd like to provide basic help documentation along with each UDF.

My current solution is to include a worksheet explaining the UDFs within each add-in along with ribbon buttons to "Open Help" (copy and make visible the Help worksheet into a new Excel window). Admittedly, this is pretty janky and also cumbersome to update.

I've also considered giving help via a MsgBox() such that each UDF `=UDFname()` would have a  `=UDFname_help()` but that isn't obvious to the user. Neither is a separate help file located in the add-in directory. I've got to believe there is a more elegant solution?

Considering the add-ins will contain multiple UDFs, what is best practice for documenting the purpose, limits, and parameter requirements?

Comment: Have you seen the post about [Application.MacroOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987037/add-help-to-no-help-available-excel-vba-user-defined-functions)

Comment: Thanks, Siddharth. The Application.MacroOptions is placed inside the body of the function?

Comment: No it is not. It is saved in that workbook. So if you convert that workbook to an Addin then you will have to call that from it. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41144765/when-to-set-macrooptions-for-excel-addin) example.